# How can I insert a long XML string into a blob in pl/sql?

Tags: oracle, plsql, blob

I have an XML string that has more than 5000 characters. I have to store this XML string in an Oracle db having blob as the data type as shown by the toad.

How can it be stored?

Comment: just a question: is there a specific reason you are storing the data as a blob rather than a clob?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
insert into tabbleName values(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(varchar2Data));
```

varchar2 has size 4000 as column and 32767 as variable.